# Bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails gem - Trouble seeing the full calendar when at the bottom of a page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, css, rubygems, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using the gem Bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails (found here: https://github.com/TrevorS/bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails), along with Bootstrap 3 on rails 3.2.

I happened to have my datetime field at the very bottom of a page. When I click on the calendar icon, part of the calendar widget shows, the rest is clipped and scrolling down the page is needed (the page's vertical scrollbar shows). However, to grab the page vertical scroll bar, the calendar is hidden since it lost its focus.

Any suggestions on how I may resolve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding margin-bottom to the last div in my page, so that there is always some space to accommodate the calendar when it unfolds. I think that's the easiest way to get around this for now.